# How to verify that the checkbox is checked with rc-forms package?

Tags: reactjs, validation, rc-form

When user is registering, I would like to check that TOS (Terms of service) have been read and accepted. To do that, there is a checkbox on my forms "I accept the TOS"

[image]

I'm using [rc-form package](https://github.com/react-component/form) to validate my reactstrap forms, but I don't find how to verify (via rc-form) that the checkbox is checked. Is there a solution using rc-form to avoid manual tests?

In this sample, tosErrors stay empty even if TOS checkbox is unchecked

```js
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.props.form.validateFields((error) => {
    if (!error) {
      const { register } = this.props;
      const { email, password, read } = this.state;

      //HERE IS A MANUAL TEST BECAUSE rules on checkbox are not working
      if (read) {
        register(email, password);
      }
    }
  });
}

render() {
  //...some code was removed because unuseful for stackoverflow question...
  const { getFieldProps, getFieldError, getFieldValue } = this.props.form;
  const tosErrors= getFieldError("read");

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      //... some form elements ...
      <FormGroup check>
        <Col sm={{ size: 8, offset: 4 }}>
          <Label check>
            <Input
              type="checkbox"
              name="read"
              id="read"
              className={tosErrors ? "is-invalid" : ""}
              {...getFieldProps("read", {
                initialValue: read,
                rules:[{"required":true}], <==== THE RULES
                onChange,
                valuePropName: "checked"
              })}
            />
          </Label>
          // BELOW THIS IS ONE OF MY MANUAL TEST because tosErrors stay empty
          {getFieldValue("read") || <HelpBlock color={"danger"}>{t("validators:accept cgu")}</HelpBlock>}
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>
      ... SOME OTHER FORM ELEMENTS
    </Form>
}
```

*rc-form package is using [async-validator](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator/) package*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add validator function to you component, before `render()`:

```
checkIsChecked = (rule, value, callback) => {
    if (value === false) {
        callback("You should agree with Terms of Service!");
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}
```

And then add validator with this function to `rules`:

```
rules: [{ required: true }, {
    validator: this.checkIsChecked,
}],
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry I didn't accept your answer. My bad!